# How to replace AAC in 265 MP4s with PCM with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to re encode my h265 files from AAC to PCM audio for the ability to edit them in Davinci Resolve.

I originally used this for h264 files and replaced the codec with `hevc_mp4toannexb out.h265` but with no luck!

```
## .sh script

#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp4; \
  do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f/%mp4/wav}"; \
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec copy -an -bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb "${f/%mp4/m4v}"; \
  ffmpeg -i "${f/%mp4/m4v}" -i "${f/%mp4/wav}" \
         -acodec copy -vcodec copy "${f/%mp4/mov}"; \
  rm "${f/%mp4/m4v}"; \
  rm "${f/%mp4/wav}"; \
done
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to re-encode the audio stream (I picked signed 16-bit, pcm_16le, but use an PCM codec of your choice). A single FFmpeg call should suffice. Something like this (I'm not familiar with sh script):

```
## .sh script

#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp4; \
  do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec pcm_16le -vcodec copy "${f/%mp4/mov}"; \
done
```

Comment: I assume it must be something  with to do with the audio codec, but Davinchi Resolve does not like the output of that as it plays a really high pitched horrible static like sound for the fast maybe 10 seconds then is slightly :(

Comment: I haven't used DaVinci Resolve in years, but I'm surprised that you cannot just load MP4 file as is. According to [their spec sheet](https://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/SupportNotes/DaVinci_Resolve_16_Supported_Codec_List.pdf) AAC is a supported codec.

Comment: What happens if you extract wav files and load them separately? `ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -acodec pcm_16le -vcodec copy "${f/%mp4/wav}"` (well, make sure that the wav file plays back properly)

Comment: Ye, I've spent a long time looking at the document... and thinking "you liars" lol but it does not support ACC audio format. It does support MP4s

Comment: Ye, I tested this exact thing, wav works perfectly by itself. But I struggle to add it back into the file. When I did, I couldn't get the correct codex for the audio with the wave so it just defaulted back to ACC audio

Comment: I meant just load the video tracks of MP4s and audio tracks from WAVs in DaVinci separately.

Comment: Ahh got you. Thing is there are many 400 files, in maybe 40 folders lol its too hard to keep track of! :(

Comment: Found [this thread with an essentially identical ffmpeg transcoding solution as I posted](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=102620#p804098). Scratching my head...

Comment: Brilliant! I will try this out :) Oddly I found that if I had previously merged/done a `copy` on a file, then the above you have suggested works perfectly! However if its "clean" directly from the camera the above ends up having no audio and that awful static!! Now that is confusing!!